# Есть ли такое свойство input?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, input

Необходимо, чтобы когда текст не помещается в `<input>` , он обрезался и в конце было "..."?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пример взял отсюда - [ссылка](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/t/text-overflow/)

```css
h1{
   text-overflow: ellipsis;
   white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<h1>оывралодлф оырлоф рывлофр лыф рлофыврлоф ывлорфы ловр</h1>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое

Comment: @Yaroslav Я думаю, ты понимаешь, что вместо моего `h1` может быть любой тэг)